# Intuition behind the base cases of this DP

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following DP question:

> Given a list of non-negative integers representing the amount of money of each house, determine the maximum amount of money you can rob tonight without alerting the police.  You cannot rob adjacent houses since doing that would alert the police.

One of the solutions given is:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int rob(vector<int>& nums) {
        if(nums.empty())
            return 0;

        if(nums.size()==1)
            return nums[0];

        vector<int> dp(nums.size());
        dp[0] = nums[0];
        dp[1] = max(nums[0], nums[1]);

        for(int i=2; i<(int)nums.size(); i++) {
            dp[i] = max(dp[i-2]+nums[i], dp[i-1]);
        }

        return dp[nums.size()-1];
    }
};
```

Could someone please point out the intuition behind initialization of `dp[1]` as:

```
dp[1] = max(nums[0], nums[1]);
```

I initialized it as `dp[1] = nums[1]`.  However, it then breaks on test cases like `[3,1,4,10]`.  When we initialize it as `max(nums[0], nums[1]);`, aren't we **sort of** changing the input array to `[3,3,4,10]`?  How does it help us reach the final (correct) solution?

Note:  Question is from [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/house-robber/description/).

**Edit:**  Do the guidelines recommend taking into account our main DP formula while hard-coding the base cases for questions like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maximize the amount of money you can rob, you must start robbing either from the first house or the second. You cannot rob them both, since they are adjacent and this would not respect the given condition.

You cannot rob none of them since you would miss one house and it would result into a value that is not a global maximum.

That initialization can be seen as "The maximum amount you can rob starting from house 0 and going to house 1 (inclusive)". Your initialization says that the maximum you can rob from the first two houses is only 1 (not 3, as it must be), which is false, resulting into a false maximum.

Comment: Nice explanation, thank you! :)  I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Also, would I be right in generalizing that we should take into account the recursion formula while generating the base cases?

Comment: This is a bottom up DP approach - global maximum is obtained by building up on a base case. The recursive formula itself is based on the last two computed maximums. You could not generate the base case using this formula, since the values used by it do not exist (according to the formula, you would need `dp[-2]` and `dp[-1]`, which is invalid).

Comment: Yes, I understand that.  I am asking about _how to_ generate the bases cases; not whether we should generate them.  The answer to if we should generate is obvious to me.  I wish to know how to generate them.

Comment: The base case varies from DP problem to DP problem, however identifying the base case and recursive formula becomes easier as you do more problems. Practicing will show you that many DP problems are similar and can be solved using a similar approach.